# Why cannot I access field in a method of same class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

Following is part of my code for component

```
export class RootComponent{
iSActive = true;

  setVal(j){
     if(j==0){
        isActive = false;
     }
  }

}
```

I am new to Angular , My question might sound silly. My question is why cant I use/set field `isActive` inside a method of same class, for example `setVal`.

Comment: `this.isActive = false;`

Comment: @R.Richards Thats correct , can you write the answer with an explanation please so that I can accept it

Comment: Always use `this` when you are doing reference to class properties/methods. You only will use them without `this` when the var (`let`, `const`) declared is in the function scope and when you use an exported function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to change the value of a class level variable from within a class function, you need to use the `this` keyword. `this` is what you use to tell the function what scope to use when changing variable values. Without it, the scope is really inside the function itself.

Example: `this.isActive = false;`

Answer (score 3):

Use **this** to access following variable/field

```
export class rootComponent{
   iSActive = true;

   setVal(j){
    if(j==0){
    this.iSActive = false;
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Why this ?  to access the current instance of the class ?

Comment: Because a class needs this instance to use the class scope -- So do you get it